# Aggregate query in Presto on Redshift's view failing with error org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: transaction is read-only

Tags: view, amazon-redshift, presto

When querying from presto on to redshift views with aggregate query we are getting `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: transaction is read-only` exception

We have a view

```
select count(col1) from redshift.public.my_view
```

in our redshift which we are trying to access from presto  and below is the exception full stacktrace

```
com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: ERROR: transaction is read-only
  Detail: 
    at com.facebook.presto.plugin.jdbc.JdbcRecordCursor.handleSqlException(JdbcRecordCursor.java:236)
    at com.facebook.presto.plugin.jdbc.JdbcRecordCursor.<init>(JdbcRecordCursor.java:95)
    at com.facebook.presto.plugin.jdbc.JdbcRecordSet.cursor(JdbcRecordSet.java:59)
    at com.facebook.presto.spi.RecordPageSource.<init>(RecordPageSource.java:37)
    at com.facebook.presto.split.RecordPageSourceProvider.createPageSource(RecordPageSourceProvider.java:42)
    at com.facebook.presto.split.PageSourceManager.createPageSource(PageSourceManager.java:56)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.TableScanOperator.getOutput(TableScanOperator.java:239)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processInternal(Driver.java:379)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.lambda$processFor$8(Driver.java:283)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.tryWithLock(Driver.java:675)
    at com.facebook.presto.operator.Driver.processFor(Driver.java:276)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlTaskExecution$DriverSplitRunner.processFor(SqlTaskExecution.java:1077)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.executor.PrioritizedSplitRunner.process(PrioritizedSplitRunner.java:162)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.executor.TaskExecutor$TaskRunner.run(TaskExecutor.java:483)
    at com.facebook.presto.$gen.Presto_0_219____20190520_105106_1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: transaction is read-only
  Detail: 
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:304)
    at com.facebook.presto.plugin.jdbc.JdbcRecordCursor.<init>(JdbcRecordCursor.java:92)
    ... 16 more
```

select count(mycol) from redshift.public.my_view

actual results we need to get count from the view

Comment: you are trying to access a redshift view from presto?

Comment: What's the `connection-url` in your `redshift.properties`?

Comment: @JonScott yes we are accessing redshift from presto

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen below are my connection properties
connector.name=redshift
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://[HOSTNAME]:5439/[DATABASENAME]
connection-user=USERNAME 
connection-password=PASSWORD

Comment: Let's track the issue here: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/793